# Does this create a TCP or UDP connection for the server?

Tags: python, sockets

```
from socket import *
host=gethostname()
port=7776
s=socket()
s.bind((host, port))
```

Is it UDP or TCP-IP? How do I write this as TCP-IP if it's UDP and vice  versa?

Answer (score 2):

This will create a TCP socket because the type argument of `socket.socket(...)` defaults to `SOCK_STREAM`. For UDP you would need to use `SOCK_DGRAM` as type instead. See [the extensive documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) for more details.